# How to get a subset of the arguments object? (regarding parameters with variable size)

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get a subset of the `arguments` object? For example, select only the arguments after the first one (the "tail")?

In Python it can be done like this:

```
def tail(*xs):     # * means a tuple of parameters of variable size   
    return xs[1:]  # return from index 1, to the end of the list

tail(1, 2, 3, 4)   # returns (2, 3, 4)
```

Is there a way to do something similar in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the `arguments` variable is cast to an array using `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`. As you're already calling the [`slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), you can simply add the missing parameters to that function to chop off the end of the pseudo-array:

```
function tail() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
}

tail(1, 2, 3, 4); // returns [2, 3, 4]
```